# windowSoftInputMode adjustPan does not work when EditText is moved/resized

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to use an EditText to let the user edit input on different positions of a Scrollview (like cells in a spreadsheet). When the softkeyboard is invoked, it moves the screen only as long as the Edittext is on its original location, that was given in the Layout.xml. As soon as I change something like size, location, background, the invoked Keyboard does not move the screen, but covers the Edittext when it is in the way. Same when I use adjustResize.
Is there a solution beside adding an separate EditText on every possible opsition?

Any help welcome.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this problem? I also have this problem when I translate a container with an EditText field inside. After translation, the window does not adjustPan...an Android bug I suspect

Comment: Not jet on native android. Started to try Qt (neccesitas), there it is possible to launch the keyboard on a QLineedit by giving the focus to it and afterwards simulate a touch on it by means of mouse events.

Comment: yeah I explored that workaround... not attractive, and certainly not production approved. I eventually used the ValueAnimator on the EditText box to move it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the focus of the view, things will work when system know which view have the focus, in scrollview case the focus is on the scrollview hence things will not work accordingly.can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369140/android-how-to-track-if-soft-keyboard-is-openned/12369315#12369315) for more information.