# how to check if the soft-keyboard was opened on device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

i have to detect if the soft-keyboard was opened. i have read some articles here on how to do it, one example is [>this<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369140/android-how-to-track-if-soft-keyboard-is-openned) there was another, maybe better one, but the two ar aiming at the same target, to check if the layout/View was forced to resize.

my problem here is, that that all is java code and i can't do anything with java code, because i don't know the Monodroid equivalents of the API, and some other small things...

Antoher thing i figured out is, that there is a InputMethodService.OnWindowShown() method/Event, and a identifier wheter the keyboard is shown or not.

```
var inputManager = (InputMethodService)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
inputManager.OnWindowShown();
bool bla = inputManager.IsInputViewShown;
```

is there a way to identify if the keyboard was opened, with these lines, or do i have to do the resize thing? and if the resize is the only thing, how dos it work in Mono for Android?

Answer (score 0):

You **can't detect** if soft keyboard is shown or not,but you can indirectly know that a soft key board is shown by knowing that **the view of your activity is resized**.
This 2 lines hide the soft keyboard..

```
var input = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
input.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText1.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
```

Also can see..

- [Android.InputMethodServices.InputMethodService.InputMethodImpl.HideSoftInput](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.InputMethodServices.InputMethodService.InputMethodImpl.HideSoftInput#)

Comment: i don't want to hide the keyboard, i want to know if the keyboard was opened so i can hide a tabWidget, taking way to much space on the screen.